# Creating a shortcode with a WordPress multi-instance widget

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/WordPress_Widgets_Api

I created a simple plugin as per this post and it works great as a multi-instance widget. I can not however get a shortcode working to place in my posts to display the widget. I added this at the end of the plugin code after the widget init, but no go. Any ideas on how to get this working? thx!

```
add_shortcode("presskit-contact", "FooWidgetHandler");

function FooWidgetHandler() {$foo_output = FooWidget();return $foo_output;}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/sidebar-widgets-shortcode-wordpress/

I found this which solved my problem